# Excel: Conditional Formatting to highlight specific row based on what is below it

Tags: excel

I have an excel issue that I cant quite find a solution for after a few days of searching and trying.

I have a very large excel sheet that is has blocks of data that are only divided by a bottom border for the end of the block. Specifically the cell that contains SECONDARY as the value (or row 7 in this example), with the row below it being the start of the next block, hence the blank description.

I have conditional formatting set to highlight 4040 in one color. I also have formatting set to highlight 0047, 0620, 0050, 0056, 0053, and 0623 in another color as these are all the same and have the same description.

With that I manually highlight Row 1 of the block in blue if it has both 4040 and one of or all 0047 through 0623. Otherwise if it only has 4040 I highlight Row 1 of that block in green. If it has any of 0047-0623, I highlight it in red..

I dont want to manually scroll through the sheet looking for either color then manually highlighting the beginning block (row 8 in this case), thats what Im looking to solve but am struggling to find something to do that.

[Here is an image example of what im trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13xkO.jpg)

> Block contains orange and yellow, the first row gets highlighted in
> blue.
>
> Block contains just yellow, highlight first row in red.
>
> Block contains just orange, highlight first row in green.

Hopefully someone has an idea of how I can create something that goes through the sheet and highlights the first row of the block for me depending on what is in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't base conditional formatting on another colour, but you can base it on a formula, as you can see in following screenshot:

[image]

The two formulas are (defined for cell "B2", and then applied everywhere):

```
=$B3=4040 (colour red)    Stop when true : X
=$B2=4040 (colour yellow)
```

So, the following happens:

When the next line (fix column "B", hence `$B`) is 4040, the line become red. Do nothing more.
When the line itself (fix column "B", ...) is 4040, the line becomes yellow.